# What's the advantage of Jupyter notebooks over any other setup where an editor is linked to a terminal

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I read and heard a lot about Jupyter notebooks recently. I gave them a try and found it terribly obstructing to basically have to use an editor with the functionality of Windows' Notepad. Besides that I feel like I didn't get the fundamental point of Jupyter notebooks:

Can I not achieve everything that Jupyter does by editing plain `.py` files in any editor that is linked to a Python/IPython console? Specifically, I can edit Python code and run parts of it using the standard Spyder setup

[image: https://www.spyder-ide.org/static/images/spyder_website_banner.png]

or even with a properly setup Vim or Emacs.

The big difference being of course that any of these three setups gives me incredibly much more power to do all the other things that facilitate coding, like fast editing commands, code completion, debugging, refactoring, ...

Answer (score 0):

You can save results and graphs of your runs like a report.

And it is better readable.

It is very good to share your results with others.